# find and replace tuples in a list from another list of tuples by maintaining order python

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples

I'm trying to find and replace the tuples from a list in python. Here is example:

```
 tup_list = [(u'I', u'NSUBJ'), (u'had', u'INTAKE'), (u'3', u'QUANTITY'), 
 (u'slices', u'UNIT'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'chicken fajita 
 pizza',u'FOOD'), (u'and', u'CC'), (u'a', u'DT'), 
 (u'cup', u'UNIT'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'coffee', u'FOOD'), (u'this', 
 u'DT'), (u'morning', u'TIMESLOT')]
```

after getting the food tuples from tup_list:

```
food_list = [x for x in tup_list if x[1] == "FOOD"]
food_list
[(u'chicken fajita pizza', u'FOOD'), (u'coffee', u'FOOD')]
```

doing some processing I get following list of tuples of food_list

```
food_list =  [(u'chicken fajita', u'FOOD', 1),(u'||',u'F'),
(u'pizza',u'FOOD', 1),(u'||',u'F'),(u'coffee', u'FOOD'),(u'||',u'F')]
```

Now I want to replace the

> (u'chicken fajita pizza',u'FOOD')

with

> (u'chicken fajita', u'FOOD', 1)(u'pizza', u'FOOD', 1)

and the ordered of the tuples should be the same after inserting the above tuples. Same should be applied to `(u'coffee', u'FOOD')` tuple and the result should look like this.

```
tup_list
[(u'I', u'NSUBJ'), (u'had', u'INTAKE'), (u'3', u'QUANTITY'), 
(u'slices', u'UNIT'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'chicken fajita', u'FOOD', 1),
(u'pizza', u'FOOD', 1), (u'and', u'CC'), (u'a', u'DT'), 
(u'cup',u'UNIT'),(u'of', u'IN'), (u'coffee', u'FOOD', 1), 
(u'this',u'DT'), (u'morning', u'TIMESLOT')]
```

here is the code which have some issues

```
for idx, tup in enumerate(food_list):
    for i, t in enumerate(tup_list):
        c = i
        if t[1] in tup[1]:
            for k, l in enumerate(food_list):
                if l[1] == "FOOD":
                    print("replacing ", t)
                    print("inserting", l)
                    print("at===", c)
                    tup_list.insert(c, l)
                    c += 1
                    print(c)
                    print("popping from verified food", l)
                    food_list.pop(k)
                else:
                    break
            print("popping", tup_list[c])
            tup_list.pop(c)
            break
```

it replaces the food but with wrong order and also omit the `(u'coffee', u'FOOD')` tuple, here is the output:

```
tup_list
[(u'I', u'NSUBJ'),
(u'had', u'INTAKE'),
(u'3', u'QUANTITY'),
(u'slices', u'UNIT'),
(u'of', u'IN'),
(u'chicken fajita', u'FOOD', 1),
(u'pizza', u'FOOD', 1),
(u'coffee', u'FOOD'),
(u'and', u'CC'),
(u'a', u'DT'),
(u'cup', u'UNIT'),
(u'of', u'IN'),
(u'coffee', u'FOOD'),
(u'this', u'DT'),
(u'morning', u'TIMESLOT')]
```

Comment: What's the rule used to turn `chicken fajita pizza` into `chicken fajita`, `pizza`  (i.e. what's the rule for splitting)?

Comment: I have a db which contains the food names. I searched it from db and making a list.